# Jquery datepicker is getting overlapped by input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

[As you can see in the image the Jquery datepicker is overlapped by input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zo9q.png)

input is a Kartik Krajee bootstrap photo upload plugin[link:http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo]

HTML

```
  <input id="file-0a" class="file" name="file" type="file" size="" multiple data-min-file-count="1">
```

Jquery Date picker

```
     <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob" class="form-control"  placeholder="Date of Birth">
           <?php
     $year = date('Y');
       ?>

 <script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({changeYear:true, yearRange: '<?php echo $year-70; ?>:<?php echo $year-10; ?>'});
          });

  </script>
```

the Photo upload input is overlapping the calendar as you can see the image can any one fix this??

Comment: i did add z-index:0px through inspect element and is did work but i dont know where to add in the file

Comment: You can add it via css rules and apply `z-index: 0px` inside of a class/id, or do in-line css for that element like `style="z-index: 0px"`

Comment: i did but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

First, find datepicker container css class. There is an easy way to do this with Chrome Developer Tools. Right click the datepicker when it is open of course and click "Inspect" in Chrome. You can see the root (or container) html element that shows the datepicker. Take it's class (or id) and apply the css rule below.

```
#datepicker-container-or-something {
 z-index:9999 !important;
}
```